# I am a newbie about bower. How can I set central repository and make every projects reference it?

Tags: bower, bower-install

Like the title, I am a newbie about bower. I want to make central repository. Because I have to make many prototype projects using bower. Whenever I make the project and finish making the bower.json file, I have to download the dependency into my local repository located in the below directory of each projects.

How can I set central repository and make every projects reference it?

Comment: But what if you need different lib versions within different projects? Wouldn't the central repo break your dependency list? I mean that's why you have it split into different folders.

Comment: OK. I know what you said. But what if every projects have same libraries with same versions and share repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Projects should not share bower dependencies. Keep track of which version you use in the `"dependencies"` object of your `bower.json` and re-download each dependency per project every single time.

You won't notice any impact on disk space, and dealing with version mis-matches or breaking changes is not worth your time. If it works, freeze the version.

---

That said, you can use a `.bowerrc` json file and the `"directory"` field to save components anywhere in the file system.

See http://bower.io/docs/config/

You can use a [symlink](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) to reference dependencies. Not sure why you'd want to, but you can.

Please note `bower` isn't `npm` and you still need to manually include files in a build system or reference them from the html one at a time.

Comment: Thanks, Like I added the comment in my question, There are a few projects that share same libraries with same versions. I will use the property of directory in .bowerrc file.